# Deleting all instances of resource type across multiple/all Kubernetes namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, cert-manager, kubectl

I'm trying to uninstall and reinstall cert-manager on our Kubernetes clusters. Their [uninstall docs](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/uninstall/kubernetes/) mention:

> Before continuing, ensure that all cert-manager resources that have
> been created by users have been deleted. You can check for any
> existing resources with the following command:
>
> `$ kubectl get Issuers,ClusterIssuers,Certificates,CertificateRequests,Orders,Challenges --all-namespaces`

The command outputs hundreds of resources, spread across two dozen namespaces.

How can I efficiently delete them all, without deleting anything else in the namespaces?

The `kubectl delete` command requires specifying a namespace when deleting all of a certain type, like this: `kubectl delete certificates -n example-ns`, so that's no good here.

Deleting each one by name in a loop while specifying `-A` also doesn't work, since I need to specify the namespace:

```
$ kubectl delete -A order.certmanager.k8s.io/fcfa95477bc0149dbc16c99c54faa82e-cert-1862418815
error: a resource cannot be retrieved by name across all namespaces
```

What's the correct cli magic here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should delete the whole `crd` (Custom Resource Definition), first list your CRDs with

```
kubectl get crd
```

and then delete the CRD, with e.g. (using `Issuer` as example)

```
kubectl delete crd issuer.<something>.<something>
```

When the CRD is deleted, also all instances of that CRD (e.g. all resources of `kind: Issuer`) is deleted.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. After deleting the relevant CRD's it was a bit scary seeing error messages, but they disappeared soon enough. I suppose there's a finalizer running that performs cleanup of the dependent resources when their CRD is deleted.